# Firestore data bundles in Sveltekit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to implement data bundles into my Sveltekit project with [Firestore Bundle Builder](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/firestore-bundle-builder) which creates a cloud function upon installation.

To use this function I am using Firebase hosting together with [svelte-adapter-firebase](https://github.com/jthegedus/svelte-adapter-firebase) but the adapter doesn't seem to accept the dashes in the function name when reading it from firebase.json.

> Error: Cloud Function name must use only alphanumeric characters and
> underscores and cannot be longer than 63 characters

```
"rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "/bundles/*",
                "function": "ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve"
            }
        ]
```

- Can I rename the function and http request?
- Do I still need the cloud function if I go the route of saving it in storage instead of using a cdn?
- Is there any other way to circumvent this?

I am new to using data bundles and cloud functions so any help is appreciated!